# Simple recursive harmonic method

Tags: java, recursion, computer-science

I have a simple recursive harmonic method:

```
 public static int harmonicOf(int n)

{ 
  if(n==1)
  {
      return 1;
  }
  return 1/n + harmonicOf(n-1);
}
```

It always returns `1` and I understand why it does that. I also know that if I switch everything from `int` to `double` it works then too.

I'm just really curious as to why that is - why when it's double does it not also return `1` and is there any possible way to use `int`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use integer variable to store floating values. So simply you can't make it with int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an integer 1/n will be equal to zero when n>2.
That's because (for example) 1/3 is actually 0 since it's evaluated in terms of an integer.
And finally when you get 0 + harmonicOf(2-1) after multiple recursions , it'll return 1 since harmonicOf(1) is 1.

If you wanna fix it up, dont use an integer, use a float or double. That way 1/n for any value of n>1 will be evaluated as a decimal and not as 0

Answer (score 1):

If the method returns an int, `1/n + harmonicOf(n-1)` is evaluated as an int. This means that `1/n` would be zero for each `n > 1`. That's why `1` is returned.

If the method returns float or double, `1/n + harmonicOf(n-1)` is evaluated as float or double (based on the return type of `harmonicOf(n-1)`). That's why `1/n` is also evaluated as float or double, and can be non zero.